# Exception with KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, in Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, hadoop

I work with hadoop in eclipse using the maven plugin,
and I try to do chaining map reduce functions, and in the second map I use 
KeyValueTextInputFormat.class as an input file class, instead of the TextInputFormat.class. Becuase I want to pass "Text" as a key with the map not LongWritable.
And when I do that I got this exception, I tried all the solutions that I found it here in the stackoverflow.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but interface was expected
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat.isSplitable(KeyValueTextInputFormat.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
```

the Driver class:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

    // Create job1
    Job job1 = new Job(conf, "job1");
    job1.setJarByClass(Mapper1.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
    job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(ByteWritable.class);
    job1.setMapOutputValueClass(RowNumberWritable.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(Reducer1.class);
    job1.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, inputPath);
    job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    Path path1 = new Path(out1);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, path1);
    job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    // Delete output if exists
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    if (hdfs.exists(countedPath))
        hdfs.delete(countedPath, true);

    // Execute the job1
    int code = job1.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

    // Create job2
    Job job2 = new Job(conf, "WordPerDocument");
    job2.setJarByClass(Mapper2.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(Mapper2.class);
    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(WordDocumentWritable.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(Reducer2.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, path1);
    job2.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    Path path2 = new Path(ou2);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, path2);
    job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    code = job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

and my imports are:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

Please, If anyone now any idea of this crazy exception:(
Thanks all

Comment: you should post some code with that.. it is really hard to guess which kind of code produce that particular error

Comment: I add the driver class.

Comment: Can you include your imports. Its likely you're mixing `mapred` and `mapreduce` imports.

Comment: no I didn't mix them, i upload the imports to my question. Did you think the problem from the eclipse or the dependencies ? When I run map reduce with text format it's run ok.

Comment: @BinaryNerd Hi Binary, if this KeyValueInputFormat , doesn't work with me, Can I implement a new Writable that i can use it to pass a Text key in the map ? If you know any link or example of that, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error is caused by this line

```
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, path2);
```

`job2` is a `Job` object and doesn't belong there.. you should use `TextOutputFormat.class` or something similar instead

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain what you mean more, as I see from the exception I think the error in the input format not the output.

Comment: are you sure about that?

Comment: No not sure but I think that the problem, when I search for that exception